# How to get a name from URL, PHP, Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get the name of a person from different URLs.

Examples:

URL can vary from http://www.example.com/John-Smith/

to http://www.example.com/some-other-info/hellen-leroy/

to www.example.com/some/other/info/nick-waller/

but it's not limited to these variations (only the person's name stays in format firstname-lastname)

I need to put the name of the person in a variable like this:

$personName = "Firstname Lastname";

How can I do this?
P.S. : it can be done using pure PHP or some Wordpress functions.

Comment: Take the last part of the url using **explode()**, and then use **str_replace()** to replace '-' with a space. You may also want to check the **ucfirst()** function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$temp = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$temp = explode('-', $temp[count($temp)-1];
$firstName = $temp[0];
$lastName = $temp[1];
```

Hope that helps :)